# SQL Server using partition_by

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Server table I'm querying that I need to only return those `sales_pers_id` that have more than one `sales_state`. Should I use `partition_by`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT sales_pers_id, sales_state
FROM dbo.sales_history
ORDER BY sales_pers_id

sales_pers_id    sales_state
1653             NE
1677             MS
1677             NC
1701             AL
1701             HI
```

So from this I need only to return #'s 1677 and 1701

Comment: Please provide both sample input data and expected outcome as tables in a form someone can read it.

Comment: Hint- `group by & having`

Comment: You have DISTINCT in your explanation/sample data. If you don't have distinct, do you end up with multiple records where there are only distinct here? Can you share actual sample data and not manipulated sample with the DISTINCT as it may very well change the answer.